# Selenium (Python) gets stucked while scraping data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I´m trying to scrape some products of Amazon but while the program is scraping it gets stuck. This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver.exe', options = options)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.es/")

buscador = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/input')
buscador.send_keys('Tarjetas gráficas', Keys.RETURN) # Searches 'Tarjetas gráficas' (graphic cards) on Amazon

btn_cookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/span/form/div[2]/span[1]/span').click() # Accept cookies

lista_nombres = [] # List of product's names
lista_precios = [] # List of product's prices
n = 0

for j in range(7):
    n += 1
    s = 0
    time.sleep(1)

    try: # This try-except is because when the program doesn't find more items it sends an error, then it should stop scraping.
        while True:
            try:
                driver.get('https://www.amazon.es/s?k=Tarjetas+gráficas&page={}'.format(n))
                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/span[3]/div[2]/div[' + str(s) + ']/div/span/div/div/div/div/div[2]/h2/a')))
                btn_articulo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/span[3]/div[2]/div[' + str(s) + ']/div/span/div/div/div/div/div[2]/h2/a').click()
                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'productTitle')))
                nombre = driver.find_element_by_id('productTitle')
                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'priceblock_ourprice')))
                precio = driver.find_element_by_id('priceblock_ourprice')
                driver.get('https://www.amazon.es/s?k=Tarjetas+gráficas&page={}'.format(n))
                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'a-size-base-plus.a-color-base.a-text-normal')))

                lista_nombres.append(nombre)
                lista_precios.append(precio)
                print(len(lista_nombres)) # I print de length of the two lists to see if the program is scraping the data
                print(len(lista_precios))
                s += 1
            except:
                s += 1
                driver.get('https://www.amazon.es/s?k=Tarjetas+gráficas&page={}'.format(n))
                driver.set_page_load_timeout(10) 
    except:
        print('Finished')



df = pd.DataFrame({'Nombre':lista_nombres, 'Precio':lista_precios})
print(df)

df.to_excel('Tarjetas gráficas Amazon.xlsx', index = False)

time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

This is the output:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
8
8
9
9
10
10
11
11
12
12
```

As you can see when it reaches the product number 12 it gets stuck there, however, it does not send any error message or whatever. I don't know what to do, I need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reconsider using `while True` and you also should keep in mind that `try except` in `while` block would catch **ALL** the errors, thus making it impossible to exit

Comment: But how can I do this to make it work properly? I don't know what do you mean with this answer...

Comment: Okay, i did try to run your code on my side and was quite unsure, `Keys.RETURN` on line 16 isn't defined, and I couldn't found a definition elsewhere, can you provide the last working example of the code?

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten to paste the 'Keys' import, you only need to use the same code with this line: `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`